# Convert datetime variable into string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Anyway I can convert a datetime variable into string in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
select convert(varchar(100),getdate(),110)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx